# ROS Answers SE migration: MacPorts & ROS

Tags: ros, cmake, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to install ROS on a fresh OS X with Homebrew (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/), but it didn't worked correctly... So i switched back to MacPorts. After installing different ports, i tried to build ROS. It did not work. I had to add *-I/opt/local/include* to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS and now it would compile but there are linker failures?¿?

> ld: warning: ignoring file /opt/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

When i run make with VERBOSE=1, this are the last line of output

> Linking CXX executable ../../bin/rxconsole
> cd /Users/emkei/ros-underlay/build/rx/rxtools && /opt/local/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/rxconsole.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
> /usr/bin/c++   -I/opt/local/include -I/opt/local/include/wx-2.8 -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names   CMakeFiles/rxconsole.dir/src/rxconsole/rxconsole.cpp.o  -o ../../bin/rxconsole  -L/opt/local/lib ../../lib/librxtools.dylib ../../lib/librosconsole.dylib ../../lib/libroscpp.dylib ../../lib/librostime.dylib ../../lib/libroscpp_serialization.dylib ../../lib/libxmlrpcpp.dylib ../../lib/libroslib.dylib ../../lib/librosconsole.dylib /opt/local/lib/liblog4cxx.dylib ../../lib/librostime.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_date_time-mt.dylib ../../lib/libroscpp_serialization.dylib ../../lib/librospack.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_filesystem-mt.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_system-mt.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_program_options-mt.dylib -L/opt/local/lib -arch i386 -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework System -framework QuickTime -framework OpenGL -framework AGL -lwx_macu_richtext-2.8 -lwx_macu_aui-2.8 -lwx_macu_xrc-2.8 -lwx_macu_qa-2.8 -lwx_macu_html-2.8 -lwx_macu_adv-2.8 -lwx_macu_core-2.8 -lwx_base_carbonu_xml-2.8 -lwx_base_carbonu_net-2.8 -lwx_base_carbonu-2.8 /opt/local/lib/libboost_thread-mt.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_regex-mt.dylib /opt/local/lib/libboost_signals-mt.dylib
> ld: warning: ignoring file CMakeFiles/rxconsole.dir/src/rxconsole/rxconsole.cpp.o, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (i386)
> *... AND SO ON ...*
> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
> "_main", referenced from:
> start in crt1.10.6.o
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> make[2]: *** [bin/rxconsole] Error 1
> make[1]: *** [rx/rxtools/CMakeFiles/rxconsole.dir/all] Error 2
> make: *** [all] Error 2

Why want cmake link with flag *-arch i386*? Is there a reason for this?

(The port boost was not compiled as universal.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37728/macports-&-ros/) by [mano](https://answers.ros.org/users/2635/mano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2012-07-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Fuerte is not officially supported on MacPorts, and, if you attempt to install things like 'rx', you're gonna have a bad time.

You're best bet for support is to stick with Homebrew, or you're going to have to be willing to fight out the compile errors with MacPorts and will also have to remove things like rx that cause mixed linking issues because wx doesn't have a proper 64-bit port.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2012-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

wxPython 2.9 from http://wxpython.org/ works fine (64 Bit-Version).

Instead of clang i used llvm-gcc cause there is a problem with clang and wxWidgets (see https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/wx-users/klVz92qxDD8).

---

Originally posted by [mano](https://answers.ros.org/users/2635/mano/) with karma: 141 on 2012-07-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1